# Landing pages in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to create landing pages in Drupal6.

Does any body have any idea how we can create landing pages ?

Landing page" is a marketing term that describes a page on your site that a visitor is directed to from an outside source.

Thanks

Comment: You mean an `index page` in developer terms ?

Comment: No not a index page.
A page on your site that a visitor is directed to from an outside source.

Comment: There's no real answer to this question. A landing page could be a single node or a view or anything.

Comment: You don't need to do anything different to normal. It's just another node.

Answer (score 2):

**for Drupal 6**

The [landing page](http://drupal.org/project/landing_pages) module is available. But it not available for drupal7.

**For Drupal 7**

1. For the content: Use an approriate content type or view.
2. For the URL use an URL alias to get something like www.mysite.com/landingpage .
3. If you want to hide some blocks on the landing page add a PHP snippet in the block configuration which queries `arg()` or `$_GET['q']` for the URL.
4. If you need an other theme have a look at the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.
5. Use the [Nodewords: D6 Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module to add meta tags for SEO or Facebook open graph tags.
6. Use the statistics or [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module to track the succses of your page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a number of drupal sites that direct traffic to other "affiliate" sites as well as I have traffic directed to me.

My personal understanding of a landing page, in marketing terms, is a page that is more likely to convert traffic into "sales".

When you consider drupal, you cannot view it in the old fashioned hierarchy structure as that structure no longer exists. You are however given this illusion if you are using url aliases, however all drupal pages are listed at www.yoursite.com/node/nid, even your index/homepage has a url like this, you just don't see it.

Anyway, I view a landing page as a highly convertable page,
You would obviously then need to theme your page or design to be more convertable.

If you mean by landing page that this is the page listed in google rankings... then you need to go the SEO root.

But truthfully, it is too broad of a topic to give you a straight answer without you giving us your description of landing page... set the boundaries for us and we'll try the best we can to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to be able to do is redirect your users to a node/page if they come from an external referer?

You'll need to create a normal node then create a module which redirects user depending on their refereral. I think you can use this [module](http://drupal.org/project/context_http_headers) to know where the user is coming from.

The module recommended by Rikesh seems to do that but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Amandeep, if you can outline what your criteria are for a landing page, it would help us create better answers.

As SpaceBeers said, any page "can" be a langing page.  But if you want to be able to track übercart purchases that come from a particular source, or if you want to use the same landing page for multiple outside sources but track the number of hits from those referrers, it may be that you'll have an easier time doing this sort of thing using Google Analytics.  Look for details on "Funnels".  You can also us analytics software to compare results from different sources (referrers) that match a particular start page.

Basically, since "landing page" is a marketing term rather than a technical term, you need to provide more details as to what you're looking for when you ask questions in a forum like StackOverflow.